# Android layouts, how to make two items in a line

Tags: android, button, mobile, android-layout

I am beginner in android. And i could not understand differences between layouts. i want to make a button and next to button i want to set an image. So which layout should i have yo use and how can i set the positions.(Programitacilly)

Comment: You also need to accept answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to visit this page:

[Common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the LinearLayout - inside the linear layout you can place your button and image.

There's a good tutorial on how to use LinearLayout over here:
[Android Developers-LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html)

If you are new to Android, I would recommend checking out the other "Hello *" tutorials over there.

Answer (score 0):

Cemal wanted to see this done programatically. The above references are good for showing the XML versions.  Here is a quick example of the button and image in a linear layout done entirely programtically.

```
package com.example.android.ProgramLinearActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ProgramLinearActivity extends Activity {
   private static final int HORIZONTAL = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
      linearLayout.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL); //HORIZONTAL is default but here for clarity

      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
      imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.icon);

      Button button = new Button (this);
      button.setText("Test");

      linearLayout.addView(button);
      linearLayout.addView(imageView);

      setContentView(linearLayout);
   }
}
```

Hit ctrl+space a lot in the eclipse editor to see tutorials on the other attributes for the button and imageview wigets.